# How appropriate is one column table

Tags: sql, database-design

Does this kind of design come along with overhead or data redundancy?
The structure of tables should **remain** able to do **CRUD on tag**, for something like manga/anime tag, allowing specific resources found-able through selection of tags. * representing primary key.

```
tag     (tagID*, tagName)
tagMap  (tagSetID*, tagID*)
tagSet  (tagSetID*)
announce    (announceID*, tagSetID, title, content)
```

Comment: What is a tagset, and does it have any other attributes, like a name?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I personally think it act as a pointer, point to the tagMap. That is, from tagMap we can find all tags we set for each announce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing at all wrong with your design.  Most of the time, we might expect the `tagSet` table to also maybe have a name column, e.g.

```
tagSet (tagSetID*, tagSetName)
```

That you don't have one isn't really an issue.  This is really a standard many to many relationship between tags and sets, with the `tagMap` table serving as the junction table.